# Rails Error: Sprockets::FileNotFound in Users::Sessions#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

The following error occurred while executing the project after git clone, yarn install and bundle install.

Error logs

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound in Users::Sessions#new
Showing /Users/{...}/Desktop/{my_project_dir}/app/views/users/sessions/new.html.erb where line #9 raised:

couldn't find file 'angular/1.8.0/angular' with type 'application/javascript'
Checked in these paths:
  /Users/{...}/{my_project_dir}/app/assets/config
  /Users/{...}/{my_project_dir}/app/assets/fonts
  /Users/{...}/{my_project_dir}/app/assets/images
  /Users/{...}/{my_project_dir}/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/{...}/{my_project_dir}/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/{...}/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rails_admin-2.0.2/app/assets/images
  /Users/{...}/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rails_admin-2.0.2/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/{...}/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rails_admin-2.0.2/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/{...}/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rails_admin-2.0.2/vendor/assets/fonts
  /Users/{...}/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rails_admin-2.0.2/vendor/assets/images
  /Users/{...}/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rails_admin-2.0.2/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/{...}/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rails_admin-2.0.2/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/{...}/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/remotipart-1.4.4/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/{...}/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/nested_form-0.3.2/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/{...}/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails-6.0.1/app/assets/images
  /Users/{...}/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails-6.0.1/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/{...}/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails-6.0.1/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/{...}/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/jquery-rails-4.4.0/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/{...}/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/apidoco-1.6.2/app/assets/config
  /Users/{...}/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/apidoco-1.6.2/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/{...}/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/apidoco-1.6.2/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/{...}/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts
  /Users/{...}/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.0.3.4/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/{...}/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activestorage-6.0.3.4/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/{...}/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionview-6.0.3.4/lib/assets/compiled
  /Users/{...}/{my_project_dir}/node_modules):
     6:
     7:         <div class="text-center w-75 m-auto">
     8:           <a href="/">
     9:             <span><img src="<%= image_url('bi.png') %>" alt="" height="50" /></span>
    10:           </a>
    11:           <p class="text-muted mt-3"> Title description </p><p class="text-muted"></p>
    12:         </div>
```

I don't understand why `couldn't find file 'angular/1.8.0/angular' with type 'application/javascript'` is happened.

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3', '>= 6.0.3.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.4', '< 0.6.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
# gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Json Serializer
gem 'fast_jsonapi'

# api docs
gem 'apidoco'

# admin
gem 'rails_admin', '~> 2.0'

# control cors
gem 'rack-cors'

# pagination
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'

# api call
gem 'rest-client'

# user and admin
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise-jwt'
gem 'omniauth-oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-naver'
gem 'devise-i18n'

# manage role
gem 'cancancan'
gem 'rolify'

# active storage
gem 'active_storage_validations'
gem 'aws-sdk-s3'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Scheduled Job
gem 'whenever'

# Active Job
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'connection_pool'
gem 'redis-namespace'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

First of all I haven't written any angular related code within the project.

i've tried

1. I deleted the error code and tried again, but the same problem occurs with other erb code.
2. I thought maybe it could be a version of the gem files. After deleting all gems, I reinstalled ruby (using rbenv), but I got the same error.
3. I have installed angular@1.8.0, but I got the same error.

Please let me know solution about `couldn't find file 'angular/1.8.0/angular' with type 'application/javascript'`

Comment: Did you run `yarn install`?

Comment: @BroiSatse oh, I didn't write `yarn install` after cloning the git repo. sry

Comment: No worries, I keep forgetting this all the time as well! :D

Answer (score 0):

I found problem that since multiple projects are running on one server, all the projects have to be loaded locally. In the process, there was a conflict with the `apidoco` gem.

Solution is to remove `apidoco` from the Gemfile of the problem project.